# What the difference between Ruby + and concat for arrays?

Tags: arrays, ruby, concatenation, step

I've been trying to collect arrays with digits into one array. If I try to use + it returns emty array as output. Using concat returns expected array of digits. How does it work and what the main difference between these Ruby methods?

```
0.step.with_object([]) do |index, output|
  output + [index]
  break output if index == 100
do # returns empty array

0.step.with_object([]) do |index, output|
  output.concat [index]
  break output if index == 100
end # returns an array contains digits from 0 to 100
```

Comment: BTW, `output.concat [index]` is equivalent to `output << index` – you don't have to wrap a single element in an array in order to append it to another array.

Comment: There are also many better ways to achieve the goal of "collect arrays with digits into one array" your current code is equivalent to `0.upto(100).to_a`, `(0..100).to_a`, `0.upto(100).reduce([],&:<<)`, etc. However you have an `Array` of `Arrays` you are trying to collapse them `arr_of_arrs.reduce(&:concat)` would work but the simplest means would just be `arr_of_arrs.flatten`. If you want to accumulate them but maintain the inner arrays then `arr_of_arrs.reduce([],&:+)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike [`Enumerable#reduce`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce), [`Enumerable#each_with_object`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) passes the same object through reducing process.

[`Array#+`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-2B) creates a **new instance**, leaving the original object unrouched.
[`Array#concat`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-concat) **mutates** the original object.

With `reduce` the result will be the same:

```
0.step.reduce([]) do |acc, index|
  break acc if index > 100
  acc + [index]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's create two arrays:

```
a = [1, 2]
b = [3, 4]
```

Like all objects, these arrays have unique object ids:

```
a.object_id  #=> 48242540181360 
b.object_id  #=> 48242540299680
```

Now let's add them together:

```
c = a + b    #=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

This creates a new object (held by the variable `c`):

```
c.object_id  #=> 48242540315060
```

and leaves (the objects held by) `a` and `b` (and their object ids) unchanged:

```
a            #=> [1, 2] 
b            #=> [3, 4]
```

Now, let's write:

```
a += b       #=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

which Ruby changes to:

```
a = a + b
```

when it compiles the code. We obtain:

```
a            #=> [1, 2, 3, 4] 
a.object_id  #=> 48242541482040
```

The variable `a` now holds a new object that equals the previous value of `a` plus `b`.

Now let's concatenate `b` with (the new value of) `a`:

```
a.concat(b)  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4]
```

This changes (*mutates*) `a`, but of course does not change `a`'s object id:

```
a            #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4] 
a.object_id  #=> 48242541482040
```

Lastly, we could replace `a`'s value with `c`, without affecting `a`'s object id:

```
a.replace(c) #=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
a            #=> [1, 2, 3, 4] 
a.object_id  #=> 48242541482040
```

See [Array#+](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-2B), [Array#concat](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-concat) and [Array#replace](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-replace).